# Type error when passing a function to promise.then, but works fine when called with an inline function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm adding [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to an existing project that uses Redux, and I've run into some unexpected behavior with the Typescript typings. In the following code, I would expect passing `unwrapResult` to the `.then` would behave similarly to passing just `(res) => unwrapResult(res)`.

```ts
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useAppDispatch } from 'Init/store';

const pingAction = createAsyncThunk('test/ping', async (val: string) => {
    return await fetch(`${Ufcw.API_URI}/api/values`).then((res) => res.text());
});

// Inside the component...

const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const ping = () => {
    dispatch(pingAction('ping'))
        // This works fine...
        .then((res) => unwrapResult(res))
        .then((res) => console.log(res));
};

const ping2 = () => {
    dispatch(pingAction('ping'))
        // Typescript doesn't like this, but it runs fine at runtime
        .then(unwrapResult)
        .then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

In the first example, the typing work properly, and the response type gets inferred correctly. In the second though, Typescript gives the following error on the `.then(unwrapResult)`:

```
Argument of type '<R extends ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction>(returned: R) => PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<R>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: PayloadAction<string, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; }, SerializedError>) => string | PromiseLike<...>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike<string>'.
    Property 'then' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'PromiseLike<string>'.
```

In another project, it works fine, although the other project was written entirely with redux-toolkit. Both projects use the same version of Typescript, redux, react-redux, and redux-toolkit. In both projects, I'm also inferring the type of dispatch from the store:

```
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

I've also tried removing all the additional middleware that I have, and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there something obvious that I may be missing, or something I'm typing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first option works because you are defining a function which is promise like.

Reading your error it says that this type:

`<R extends ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction>(returned: R) => PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<R>`

is not assignable to this type:

`(value: PayloadAction<string, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; }, never> | PayloadAction<unknown, string, { arg: string; requestId: string; aborted: boolean; condition: boolean; }, SerializedError>) => string | PromiseLike<...>`

Because....

`Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike<string>'`

So it looks like the return of `unwrapResult` does not conform to the return the promise is expecting because it wants a `string | PromiseLike<string>` and `unwrapResult` looks like it can return an `unknown` type per the error.

Looking at the source code for `redux-toolkit`:

```
/**
 * @public
 */
export function unwrapResult<R extends ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction>(
  returned: R
): PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<R> {
  if ('error' in returned) {
    throw returned.error
  }
  return (returned as any).payload
}
```

It looks like the return type is `PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<R>` as we were expecting from the first line of the error. So here is that return type.

```
type PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<T> = T extends { error: any }
  ? never
  : T extends { payload: infer P }
  ? P
  : never
```

So as I read this, "If T extends `{error: any}` then the type is `never`." So this  can never happen. Therefore the type is

" If `T` extends `{ payload: infer P }`, it must be `P`, if it doesn't, well that'll never happen"

So I think the the return type is `P`.

So what is `P`? It's the type of `T.payload`. `T`  was the `R` from unwrapResult. Can you check that type to see the type of R and if it has a payload in your environemnt?

Also we are calling `dispatch` here... I see `useAppDispatch` is of type `store.dispatch`. I'm guessing that `store` is an `EnhancedStore` from the documentation (I've never used redux) which accepts types `<S, A>`

```
export interface EnhancedStore<
  S = any,
  A extends Action = AnyAction,
  M extends Middlewares<S> = Middlewares<S>
> extends Store<S, A> {
  /**
   * The `dispatch` method of your store, enhanced by all it's middlewares.
   *
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  dispatch: DispatchForMiddlewares<M> & Dispatch<A>
}
```

So, I'm curious when you create your store or pass it data, are you perhaps missing a type declaration or letting it infer a type that could be `unknown`, particularly the  type? That's based on this.

```
export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  <T extends A>(action: T, ...extraArgs: any[]): T
}
```

Then the action says "@template T the type of the action's `type` tag." which is being used above when extending the action.

```
/**
 * An *action* is a plain object that represents an intention to change the
 * state. Actions are the only way to get data into the store. Any data,
 * whether from UI events, network callbacks, or other sources such as
 * WebSockets needs to eventually be dispatched as actions.
 *
 * Actions must have a `type` field that indicates the type of action being
 * performed. Types can be defined as constants and imported from another
 * module. It's better to use strings for `type` than Symbols because strings
 * are serializable.
 *
 * Other than `type`, the structure of an action object is really up to you.
 * If you're interested, check out Flux Standard Action for recommendations on
 * how actions should be constructed.
 *
 * @template T the type of the action's `type` tag.
 */
export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}
```

Would be easier if I had this open in an IDE. But I think the type you are passing when creating your store, or perhaps should be specifying, would clear this up.